# PIpelineDB continuous view with mysql foreign data wrapper

Tags: mysql, postgresql, join, postgres-fdw, pipelinedb

I am getting different results when I complete a stream join on a foreign table vs when I join a continuous view to a foreign table. Two queries that I would expect to be the same appear to be different. Does the delay between my local pipeline instance and the table in the fdw have an impact on my continuous stream join? I am attempting to aggregate rx_bytes and tx_bytes baesd on an id ni the foreign tabel.

I am using the mysql_fdw from latest

https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw

1. Create a foreign table

   ```
   CREATE EXTENSION mysql_fdw;

   CREATE SERVER local_mysql
       FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql_fdw
       OPTIONS (host 'localhost', port '3306', secure_auth 'true');

   CREATE USER MAPPING FOR pipeline
       SERVER local_mysql 
       OPTIONS(username 'username', password 'password');

   CREATE FOREIGN TABLE "foo_instance" (
        "id" bigint,
        "foo_id" bigint,
   )
   SERVERlocal_mysql
   OPTIONS(dbname 'schema', table_name 'foo_instance');
   ```
2. After 10 inserts I would expect these two queries to yield the same results:

a)

```
    CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW total_bytes
    AS SELECT date_trunc('minute', time_stamp::timestamp) AS minute,
        id::integer,
        sum(tx_bytes::bigint) AS tx_bytes,
        sum(rx_bytes::bigint) AS rx_bytes
     FROM byte_count_stream GROUP BY minute, id;

    SELECT minute, sum(tx_bytes) AS tx_bytes, sum(rx_bytes) AS rx_bytes, foo_id 
    FROM total_bytes JOIN foo_instance 
         ON total_bytes.id=foo_instance.id GROUP BY minute, foo_instance.foo_id;

           minute        | tx_bytes | rx_bytes | foo_id 
    ---------------------+----------+----------+---------
     2016-02-22 09:04:00 |      450 |      513 |    7939
     2016-02-22 09:04:00 |     2762 |     2210 |    7940
     2016-02-22 09:04:00 |      143 |      332 |    7941
     2016-02-22 09:04:00 |      371 |     1042 |    7942
     2016-02-22 09:04:00 |      865 |      987 |    7943
     (5 rows)
```

b)

```
    CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW joined_foo_total_bytes
        AS SELECT date_trunc('minute', byte_count_stream.time_stamp::timestamp) AS minute,
            sum(byte_count_stream.tx_bytes::bigint) AS tx_bytes,
            sum(byte_count_stream.rx_bytes::bigint) AS rx_bytes,
            foo_instance.foo_id
        FROM byte_count_stream JOIN foo_instance ON byte_count_stream.id::integer = foo_instance.id
        GROUP BY minute, foo_instance.foo_id;



    pipeline=# select * from joined_user_total_bytes;       
           minute        | tx_bytes | rx_bytes | foo_id 
    ---------------------+----------+----------+---------
     2016-02-22 09:04:00 |      371 |     1042 |    7942
     2016-02-22 09:04:00 |      143 |      332 |    7941
     2016-02-22 09:04:00 |      865 |      987 |    7943
     2016-02-22 09:04:00 |     2762 |     2210 |    7940
     (4 rows)
```

Clearly the results are not the same. I can do the join from the continuous view to the foreign table, but would prefer to use the stream join.

Comment: Interesting, any resolution found...?